# Cannot connect to SQL Server outside of network

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection, firewall

I am running SQL Server and no matter what I do, I cannot access the server remotely using SQL Server Management Studio.

I keep getting this error:

> A network related or instance specific error while establishing the connection to the server

I am able to access the server locally but not remotely using the correct connection details hostname etc.

I have configured/ensured the following:

1. SSMS server properties -> Security -> Authentication mode: SQL Server and Windows authentication mode
2. SSMS server properties -> Connections -> Allow remote connections
3. SQL Server & SQL Server Browser services are running
4. I have to tried to ping the server, I am getting 'Request timed out' but I am able access to the web server using browser?
5. Firewall TCP port 1433 is opened
6. In SQL Server configuration manager enabled and configured TCP/IP

What else can I check?

Thanks

Comment: try https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/

Answer (score 1):

Please try to do telnet in CMD

telnet serverip 1433

If you can't connect, ask your network admin to open port 1433 for source-destination and destination-source.